# PYOMO- CPLEX PERSISTENT : TypeError: outputfile must have a write method

Tags: python, cplex, pyomo, persistent

I built a pyomo model and I am using cplex persistent to solve an abstract model like this:

```
inst = m.create_instance(dp)
opt = SolverFactory('cplex_persistent')
opt.set_instance(inst)
results = opt.solve(inst, tee=True)
print(results)
```

Error that I'm getting is

```
results = opt.solve(inst)
   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\conda_all_projects\lib\site-packages\pyomo\solvers\plugins\solvers\persistent_solver.py", line 390, in solve
_status = self._apply_solver()
   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\conda_all_projects\lib\site-packages\pyomo\solvers\plugins\solvers\cplex_direct.py", line 114, in _apply_solver
self._solver_model.set_results_stream(self._log_file)
   File "C:\Program Files\IBM\ILOG\CPLEX_Studio1210\cplex\python\3.7\x64_win64\cplex\__init__.py", line 1499, in set_results_stream
return self._env.set_results_stream(results_file, fn)
   File "C:\Program Files\IBM\ILOG\CPLEX_Studio1210\cplex\python\3.7\x64_win64\cplex\_internal\__init__.py", line 277, in set_results_stream
initerrstr=False)
   File "C:\Program Files\IBM\ILOG\CPLEX_Studio1210\cplex\python\3.7\x64_win64\cplex\_internal\__init__.py", line 254, in _set_stream
outputfile, self, fn=func, initerrorstr=initerrstr)
   File "C:\Program Files\IBM\ILOG\CPLEX_Studio1210\cplex\python\3.7\x64_win64\cplex\_internal\_ostream.py", line 66, in __init__
raise TypeError("outputfile must have a write method")
       TypeError: outputfile must have a write method
```

I don't know how to correct this error "the output file must have a writing method" the pyomo book and the information on the pyomo website don't mention anything about this

Thank you for your help

Comment: My guess is that you don't need to specify the instance again if you used `opt.set_instance(inst)`. What happens if you write `opt.solve(tee=True)` for solving your problem?

Comment: @V.Brunelle thanks for the answer, I followed your suggestion but it gives me the same error